# ExtJS ,issues with Ext.window.Window when called over other views

Tags: extjs, window

I Have defined a window class with width and height with border layout. It is working fine when displayed but when I call this window class to other view it is taking it's own size and when layout type is used the window won't be displayed at all.
I am new to ExtJS and still figuring things out

` This is my Window class
Ext.define('Task.view.a.a',{

```
    extend:'Ext.window.Window',
    title:'A- WINDOW',
    resizable:false,
    //autoShow:true,
    maxWidth:400,
    maxHeight:300,
    // layout:{
    //     type:'border'
    // },
    items:[{
        margin:'20 0 0 0',
        xtype:'panel',
        layout:'fit',
        title:'Panel in the Window',
        html:'Panel inside the window'
    }]
})`
```

`  Here is my handler function present in 'Task.view.main.Main'
handler:function(btn){
var form = this.up('form').getForm();

```
                if(form.isValid()){
                    //Ext.Msg.alert('Submitting!?','OKAY')
                    console.log(form.getValues())

                    Ext.defer(function(){
                        Ext.create('Task.view.a.a').show();
                    },2000)
                    
                }
                else{
                    Ext.Msg.alert('\'ERROR!?\' ','Please fill all the required fields')
                }
            }`
```

Comment: I would suggest to define a layout. Right now it looks like its an auto layout which might lead to the problem that the child components wont get strechted. Which is often what you want in a window. 

Define a layout like fit / v oder hbox on the window and set width and height. Furtehrmore, I would suggest you use something dynamic document.body.clientWidth * 0.8 as an example for width. But be sure to the the width like during initComponent, not as static config. 

Or create the window like its now and use methods .setWith .setHeight

Answer (score 0):

You can use

- `height/width` instead of `maxHeight/maxWidth` on Window config
- or Define the height and width of the child's item
- or Use window show listers if want to set calculated window
  dimension

Please refer to Kitchensink for more examples - https://examples.sencha.com/extjs/7.6.0/examples/kitchensink/#windows

```
        Ext.define('MyWin', {
            extend: 'Ext.window.Window',
            title: 'A- WINDOW',
            resizable: false,
            maxWidth: 400,
            maxHeight: 300,
            items: [{
                xtype: 'panel',
                layout: 'fit',
                width: 400,
                height: 300,
                title: 'Panel in the Window',
                html: 'Panel inside the window'
            }]
        });

        Ext.defer(function () {
            Ext.create('MyWin').show();
        }, 2000);
```